# Is it possible to combine SGD with an unsupervised learning approach effectively

Tags: neural-networks, backpropagation, deep-neural-networks, unsupervised-learning, stochastic-gradient-descent

Before I undertake quite a large project I would like to clarify whether my idea for training a multi-layer neural network will work. I plan to make an AI that can land a rocket from randomly generated scenarios (altitude, velocity, rotation, wind etc). I have both a rocket simulation and a back-propagating neural network which I have coded from scratch in C++. Of course the network works for standard supervised learning scenarios such as regression - however I will need to adapt it for such a project.

My plan is to calculate errors for the output layer via a brute force approach of: increase  the weighted sum by some dx and determine the change to the cost through running the scenario (which in this case looks something like this `C(finalRot, finalVx, finalVy, time)`  ), from this I will calculate the error in each neuron in the output layer - and rather than do this for the other layers I will back-propagate this error - saving a huge amount of time on calculations - and then optimise parameters conventionally as you would with a supervised model.

Before I implement this, does anyone know if such an approach is viable?

Comment: just look at RL, this is literally its application